# ¿Cómo mantener fijo el alto de un div?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy intentado crear un div con css el cual mantenga siempre su alto (heigth) en funcion de los caracteres que este contenga. Adjunto imagen de ejemplo, adjunto también el código a ejecutar con la version de bootstrap que estoy usando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la resolución se reducen estos divs no queda totalmente fijos y varian de tamaño, la idea es que queden fijos y que no varie su tamaño en cuanto al alto y siempre se mantenga el mismo tamaño.

Éste es el código y como se comportan los divs ([también en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncristiansa/nkges6qL/1/)):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <!-- Card -->

      <div class="card promoting-card">

        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body flex-row">

          <!-- Content -->
          <div>
            <!-- Subtitle -->
            <p class="card-text"><i class="pr-2"></i>Gastrointestinal Cancer—Colorectal and Anal
            </p>
            <!-- Title -->
            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-2">Nivolumab (NIVO) + low-dose ipilimumab (IPI) as first-line (1L) therapy in micro...</h4>


          </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="collapse-content">

            <!-- Text -->
            <p class="card-text">Recently, we added several exotic new dishes to our restaurant menu. They come from countries such as Mexico, Argentina, and Spain. Come to us, have some delicious wine and enjoy our juicy meals from around the world.</p>
            <!-- Button -->
            <a class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1">Abstract/Poster</a>
            <i class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1 far fa-newspaper float-right"></i>


          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Card -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card promoting-card">

        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body flex-row">

          <!-- Content -->
          <div>
            <!-- Subtitle -->
            <p class="card-text"><i class="pr-2"></i>Gastrointestinal Cancer—Colorectal and Anal
            </p>
            <!-- Title -->
            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-2">Pharmacokinetically-guided preoperative FOLFOX chemotherapy for locally advanced...</h4>


          </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="collapse-content">

            <!-- Text -->
            <p class="card-text ">Recently, we added several exotic new dishes to our restaurant menu. They come from countries such as Mexico, Argentina, and Spain. Come to us, have some delicious wine and enjoy our juicy meals from around the world.</p>
            <!-- Button -->
            <a class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1">Abstract/Poster</a>
            <i class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1 far fa-newspaper float-right"></i>


          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Card -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card promoting-card">

        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body flex-row">

          <!-- Content -->
          <div>
            <!-- Subtitle -->
            <p class="card-text"><i class="pr-2"></i>Gastrointestinal Cancer—Colorectal and Anal
            </p>
            <!-- Title -->
            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-2">Pharmacokinetically-guided preoperative FOLFOX chemotherapy for locally advanced...</h4>


          </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Card content -->
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="collapse-content">

            <!-- Text -->
            <p class="card-text ">Recently, we added several exotic new dishes to our restaurant menu. They come from countries such as Mexico, Argentina, and Spain. Come to us, have some delicious wine and enjoy our juicy meals from around the world.</p>
            <!-- Button -->
            <a class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1">Abstract/Poster</a>
            <i class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1 far fa-newspaper float-right"></i>


          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Puedes probar utilizando cards group
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups.
Para que las card no esten enlasadas unas con otras por ejemplo en el caso de querer dejar un margen podes utilizar la clase card-decks
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks.

Si queres jugar un poco mas con esto Flexbox es un modelo de layout (un valor de la propiedad display) nuevo de CSS3 (distinto a block, inline, table, etc.), que facilita alinear y distribuir elementos a lo largo de un eje sin usar floats ni position.

Flex se activa cuando un elemento tiene display: flex, que llamaremos un “flex container” y sólo afecta a sus elementos hijos directos, que llamamos “flex items”.

Un contenedor flex tiene dos ejes, el eje principal (en el que se distribuye el espacio) y el eje transversal. Esto se determina con la flex-direction: row o column. La dirección dentro de los ejes se invierte según la dirección de escritura (en árabe, por ejemplo, es al revés).

Permite alinear tanto en el eje principal (justify-content-) como en el transversal (align-items).

Usarlo con CSS puro es bastante molesto. Lo más fácil para empezar es usarlo con Bootstrap. Bootstrap provee las siguientes clases: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: Hola Martin, aunque esta respuesta puede servir de guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Edítala para añadir algo más de información (y quizás un ejemplo aplicado al código de la pregunta) y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con eso ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Comment: Buenas, en este caso me sirve este tipo d card pero como podría añadir margenes entre cada card?